# Convert super field to string/varchar in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a super field that holds JSON formatted data - `[{"Title":"First Last"}]` I want to extract the JSON value string `First Last` and to do so, I tried converting this field to varchar and the result is empty. I also tried converting to JSON_serialize and then to varchar and still the results are blank. Any help on how to fix this?

Queries i tried:

```
SET navigate_super_null_on_error=ON;  --default lax mode for navigation

SET cast_super_null_on_error=ON;  --default lax mode for casting

SET parse_super_null_on_error=OFF;  --default strict mode for ingestion

SELECT cast(MRGBackup as varchar) FROM oc_raw.rollouts;

SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier to TRUE;
 
-- Accessing JSON attribute names with uppercase and mixedcase names
SELECT 
       json_table.data."Title"
FROM
  (SELECT json_parse(mycolumn) AS data FROM mytable);
RESET enable_case_sensitive_identifier;
```

mycolumn holds data like - `[{"Title":"First Last"}]`

This throws error as - `function json_parse(super) does not exist`

Any help pls?

--------**UPDATE**--------

For my mycol = `[{"Title":"First Last"}]`

I tried this query - `SELECT mycolumn,mycolumn[0] from mytable`

and the result is `{"Title":"First Last"}` still trying to extract the inner text alone.

Comment: You probably don't need any of that `SET` stuff -- you just need to figure out how to reference the data you want. It seems to be a _List_ that contains a _Dictionary_ so presumably you would use `SELECT JSON_PARSE(field_name)[0]['Title'] from table_name` Does that work?

Comment: The `json_parse(super) does not exist` seems to be saying that `mycolumn` is already of type SUPER, so you don't need to use `JSON_PARSE()`. Try `SELECT field_name[0]['Title'] from table_name`

Comment: mycolumn is already supertype only

Comment: updated question with latest query that i tried

Comment: I don't understand why you using any set/reset part.
Try this one

```SELECT mycolumn[0]."Title" from mytable;```

Comment: this query works fine when i add set enable_case_sensitive_identifier to true; in my query session. also it works on dbeaver but not in Redshift console or VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Alright. @lex looter's answer helped. But I had to do

```
ALTER USER <username> SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier to true
```

and then do  `SELECT mycolumn[0]."Title" from mytable;` to make the query work correctly.